# Localization,translation in android: how to replace words in texts of different lengths

Tags: android, localization, translation

I have a terrible issue, my app consists of 20 activities, each activity has about 20-30 textViews, forming a story in each activity.

I have to translate it from english to russian, the problem is that **word order and length of texts is different** in both languages. Where it takes 8 words in english sentence, it takes 13-14 in same russian translated sentence. I wonder how i can translate/localize it, plus when

user presses on word, it is highlighted and sound of word is vocalized.

I have this in my values/strings.xml :

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Карандаши</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

<string name="jili">Жили-</string>
<string name="bili">были </string>

<string name="v1">в </string>
<string name="kingdom">царстве </string>

<string name="colored">"Раскрашено" </string>

<string name="funny">веселые </string>
<string name="and ">и </string>
<string name="friendly">дружные </string>
<string name="pencils">карандаши </string>
<string name="Kingdom">Царство </string>
<string name="colored">цветных </string>
<string name="pencils">карандашей </string>
```

How do i make localizations match given my requirements for every textView to be clickable and pronouncable?

Comment: You should look for layout alignment and so on. So maybe you need to change your question.